# Socket only reading in one time from client using select()

Tags: c, sockets, select

The server of this program keeps an array of ticket numbers and whether or not they are available.

The client requests to buy or return tickets from the server.

I admittedly do not really understand the select fx. From what I can tell, you load in file descriptors of sockets into a structure and select() checks if those fds are ready to read or write. Is this correct?

I need to use the select function to read in requests from 2 different clients. I think I have it working for the most part except that the server will not read in the second request from the client. The server reads in the first client request, processes it and responds, and then just hangs there waiting for the next request.

Thanks for any help, and please feel free to give me any pointers!

Server code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

void error(const char *message);
void generateTickets(int ticketArray[][2]);
void parseBuffer(char buffer[], char* request[]);
int sellTicket(int ticketArray[][2], int* refPtr);
int returnTicket(int returnTicketNumber, int ticketArray[][2], int* refPtr);
void printTickets(int ticketArray[][2]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int svrSocketFd;//file descriptor for the server side
    int cliSocketFd;//file descriptor fot the client side
    int portNum;//port number
    int readWrite;//holds the return values of the read/write functions

    socklen_t clientLength;//holds the size in bytes of the sockaddr client struct

    char buffer[256];//buffer for reading and writing

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;//server struct
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;//client struct


    fd_set readfds;
    struct timeval timeout={0,0};
    int selectReturn;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int ticketArray[25][2], returnTicketNumber;//holds ticket nums and whether or not they are avalible (0/1) 
    int ticketsAvalible = 25;//number of tickets avalible
    int *refPtr = &ticketsAvalible;
    char *request[2];//stores parsed client requests
    int i, stringComp, soldTicketNum, clientCheck;

    srand(time(0));//seed random number generator

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    generateTickets(ticketArray);

    printTickets(ticketArray);


    //check if the correct number of arguments was provided
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        error("ERROR: Port number required\n");
    }

    svrSocketFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//creates a socket for the server

    //check that the socket was created
    if(svrSocketFd < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR: Server socket not created\n");
    }

    bzero((char *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));//not really sure what this does

    portNum = atoi(argv[1]);//convert passed in port from char to int

    //set the member variables of the server sockaddr struct
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portNum);

    int on=1;
    setsockopt(svrSocketFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));

    //bind the socket to the server struct?
    if(bind(svrSocketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR: Unable to bind socket");
    }

    listen(svrSocketFd, 5);

    while(1)
    {   
        do
        {
            FD_ZERO(&readfds);
            FD_SET(svrSocketFd, &readfds);

            selectReturn = select(svrSocketFd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

            if(selectReturn > 0)
            {
                clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);//returns the size in bytes of the client struct

                cliSocketFd = accept(svrSocketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &clientLength);

                bzero(buffer, 256);//zeros out the buffer

                readWrite = read(cliSocketFd, buffer, 256);//read data in from the client)

                printf("SERVER IN buffer = %s\n", buffer);

                parseBuffer(buffer, request);//parse buffer and separate into the request array

                stringComp = strcmp(request[0], "BUY");

                if(stringComp == 0)//buy request
                {
                    soldTicketNum = sellTicket(ticketArray, refPtr);

                    bzero(buffer, 256);//zeros out the buffer

                    sprintf(buffer, "%d", soldTicketNum);

                    printf("SERVER OUT buffer = %s\n", buffer);

                    readWrite = write(cliSocketFd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

                }

                stringComp = strcmp(request[0], "RETURN");

                if(stringComp == 0)
                {
                    returnTicketNumber = atoi(request[1]);



                    if(returnTicket(returnTicketNumber, ticketArray, refPtr))
                    {
                        printf("[SERVER]: RETURNED %d\n", returnTicketNumber);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("[SERVER]: RETURNED %d failed\n", returnTicketNumber);
                    }

                }

            }

        }while(selectReturn > 0);

    }

    printTickets(ticketArray);

    //close the client and server sockets
    close(cliSocketFd);
    close(svrSocketFd);


    return 0;
}
void error(const char *message)
{
    perror(message);
    exit(1);
}

void generateTickets(int ticketArray[][2])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        ticketArray[i][0] = (rand () % 40000 + 10000);
        ticketArray[i][1] = 1;
    }
}

void parseBuffer(char buffer[], char* request[])
{       
    char *token;
    int i = 0;

    token = strtok(buffer, " ");

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        request[i] = token;
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

int sellTicket(int ticketArray[][2], int* refPtr)
{
    int i = 0;

    if(*refPtr == 0)
    {
        printf("[SERVER]: No tickets avalible\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        //searches for the first avalible ticket and returns the ticket number
        while(ticketArray[i][1] == 0)
        {
            i++;
        }

        (*refPtr)--;//decrement ticketsAvalible

        ticketArray[i][1] = 0;//set ticket as sold (0)

        return ticketArray[i][0];
    }
}

int returnTicket(int returnTicketNumber, int ticketArray[][2], int* refPtr)
{
    int i = 0;



    while(ticketArray[i][0] != returnTicketNumber && i < 25)
    {
        i++;

        if(ticketArray[i][0] == returnTicketNumber && ticketArray[i][1] == 0)
        {
            ticketArray[i][1] = 1;
            (*refPtr)++;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;


}

void printTickets(int ticketArray[][2])
{
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 25)
    {
        if(ticketArray[i][1] == 0)
        {
            printf("[Ticket # %d] %d : SOLD\n", i, ticketArray[i][0]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("[Ticket # %d] %d : AVAIL\n", i, ticketArray[i][0]);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

void error(const char *message);
int buyOrReturn();
void buyTicket(char buffer[], int ticketArray[], int* refPtr);
void returnTicket(char buffer[], int ticketArray[], int* refPtr);
void printTickets(int ticketArray[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int cliSocketFd;//hold the file descriptor for the socket
    int portNum;//port number
    int readWrite;//return values for read/write functions

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;//server struct containing the address of the server
    struct hostent *server;//defines a host computer on the internet

    char buffer[256];//buffer for reading and writing

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int requestNumber = 20;
    int ticketArray[20];//holds ticket nums 
    int ticketsAvalible = 0;//number of tickets avalible
    int *refPtr = &ticketsAvalible;
    int randomNumber;//stores a random number of either a ticket number or decision to buy/sell 
    int i;

    srand(time(0));//seed the random number generator

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        ticketArray[i] = 0;
    }

    printTickets(ticketArray);

    //check for the correct number of arguments
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        error("ERROR: Need arguments - \"hostname\" \"port number\"\n");
    }

    portNum = atoi(argv[2]);//convertargv string into an int

    cliSocketFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//open a socket

    //test is the socket was opened successfully
    if(cliSocketFd < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR: Socket did not open\n");
    }

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);//returns a pointer to a host

    //check is the system successfully located the host
    if(server == NULL)
    {
        error("ERROR: No host found\n");
    }

    bzero((char *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));//initializes serverAddress to zero

    //set the fields in serverAddress
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *) server->h_addr, (char *) &serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portNum);

    //establish and check a connection with the server
    if(connect(cliSocketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR: Could not connect to the server\n");
    }

    while(requestNumber != 0)
    {
        printf("REQUEST#: %d\n", requestNumber);
        bzero(buffer, 256);//clears the buffer

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        if(buyOrReturn())//1 buys, 0 returns
        {

            printf("CLIENT: sending buy request\n");
            strcpy(buffer, "BUY ");

            printf("CLIENT OUT buffer = %s\n", buffer);
    //RW
            readWrite = write(cliSocketFd, buffer, strlen(buffer));//send message to the server

            //check if message was not sent
            if(readWrite < 0)
            {
                error("ERROR: Message was not sent\n");
            }

            bzero(buffer, 256);//clears the buffer
    //RW
            readWrite = read(cliSocketFd, buffer, 256);

            printf("CLIENT IN buffer = %s\n", buffer);

            buyTicket(buffer, ticketArray, refPtr);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("CLIENT: sending return request\n");

            returnTicket(buffer, ticketArray, refPtr);  

            printf("CLIENT buffer = %s\n", buffer);

    //RW
            readWrite = write(cliSocketFd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        }

        requestNumber--;

    }

    printTickets(ticketArray);

    close(cliSocketFd);//close the socket

    return 0;
}

void error(const char *message)
{
    perror(message);
    exit(1);
}

int buyOrReturn()
{

    if((rand() % 4) < 3)
    {
        return 1;//buy
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;//return
    }
}

void buyTicket(char buffer[], int ticketArray[], int* refPtr)
{
    int stringCmp = strcmp(buffer, "-1");

    if(stringCmp != 0)
    {
        ticketArray[*refPtr] = atoi(buffer);

        (*refPtr)++;

        return; 
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

void returnTicket(char buffer[], int ticketArray[], int* refPtr)
{
    int randomTicketNumber;
    char returnTicketNumber[6];

    if(*refPtr == 0)
    {


        randomTicketNumber = (rand () % 50000 + 49999);

        sprintf(returnTicketNumber, "%d", randomTicketNumber);

        strcpy(buffer, "RETURN ");



        strcat(buffer, returnTicketNumber);

        printf("CLIENT buffer = %s\n", buffer);


        return;
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(buffer, "RETURN ");

        sprintf(returnTicketNumber, "%d", ticketArray[*refPtr]);

        strcat(buffer, returnTicketNumber);

        (*refPtr)--;//it is assumed that the ticket is valid and returned without error

        return;

    }
}

void printTickets(int ticketArray[])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("[Ticket # %d] %d\n", i, ticketArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The specific question you ask about (only one successful read per client) is due to your server not adding the socket that was "accepted" into your fd_set, for use the next time you "select()"... Once you do that, you will need to interrogate the fd_set you pass to select()... each one that succeeds in FD_ISSET() means it can be read from (or in the cawse of the listener socket, an accept will succeed).  There are other problems such as not detecting that the client has closed the socket... hopefully this will get you further along your task.

Comment: in any one file, a system header file only needs to be `#include`d once.  I.E. the header file: `stdlib.h` only needs to be included one time

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use consistent vertical spacing. Separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a (single) blank line.  Separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: The posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 2, 25  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: this line: `setsockopt(svrSocketFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on))`  is allowing the socket to be closed/reopened,  However, the code is missing the setting of the socket option 'keepalive' so it will close after each communication that has ANY pause before the next communication

Comment: the call to `listen()` should be followed by a call to `accept()` in the server, not a call to `select()`   Such a call to `select()` should be after the call to `accept()`, so the appropriate new/connection socket value is available.  then the code will 'sit' on the call to `accept()` waiting for a client to connect.  AFTER the client connects, then can use `select()` to wait for the client to send something.  NOTE: if you want to be able to have multiple clients active at the same time, then the code after `accept()` need to start a thread to handle the actual communication

Comment: Note: starting and stopping threads is an expensive time taker so you might want to look at using a `thread pool`

Comment: you might want to look at the `error()` function, available via `#include <error.h>`

Comment: due to precedence of C operators, this line: `ticketArray[i][0] = (rand () % 40000 + 10000);` becomes: `ticketArray[i][0] = (rand () % 50000);`  Suggest using: `ticketArray[i][0] = (rand () % 40000) + 10000;`

Comment: this line: `request[i] = token;` will assign a pointer into the `buffer[]` array to an entry in `request[]`,  however, when `buffer[]` is updated, those pointers will be wrong. (I.E. the original data will be lost.)  Suggest `request[i] = strdup(token);`   of course, later those strings will need to be passed to `free()`

Comment: why is `ticketsavailable` set to 25 when the call to `rand()` is setting the number of tickets to over 10000?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments and suggestions. The code is a complete mess due to me not knowing what I'm doing with sockets or C for that matter, so yeah, my thanks for trudging through it.